# a Proof onInverse Trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-series

Ff $\arcsin x + \arcsin z + \arcsin z = 1.5\pi$, Prove that $x^{2006}+y^{2007}+z^{2008}-\frac 9{x^{2006}+y^{2007}+z^{2008}}=0$.

Comment: You must have $x=y=z=1$, and $3-\frac{9}{3}=0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$\arcsin x\le \frac {\pi}{2}$$ If $\arcsin x + \arcsin y + \arcsin z = 1.5\pi$ then 
$$\arcsin x = \arcsin y = \arcsin z = \frac{\pi}2$$
Then $$x=y=z=1$$